# Cannot get leaflet popup to work with angularjs directive (and partial)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, leaflet

I am trying to write a directive to fill a leaflet marker pop-up.  I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.  My pop-up is always empty.

Any one successfully done this before?

Here is a plunker showing the problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/53bebb?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

marker.bindPopup(e[0]); instead of marker.bindPopup(clonedElement[0]);

Comment: That works.  Can you explain why?  I thought if you wanted to attach the element to the DOM you were supposed to use the clonedElement.  From docs: cloneAttachFn - If cloneAttachFn is provided, then the link function will clone the template and call the cloneAttachFn function allowing the caller to attach the cloned elements to the DOM document at the appropriate place. The cloneAttachFn is called as:
cloneAttachFn(clonedElement, scope)

Comment: From the angular doc: "clonedElement - is a clone of the original element passed into the compiler"
So I suppose that this element is still not been compiled and linked.

Comment: For some reason, this no longer works in angular 1.2, the controller cannot access the directive's getContent(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var directiveTag = $(document.createElement("search-results-map-marker-popup"));
var compiledDirective = $compile(directiveTag)(popupScope);

newMarker.bindPopup(compiledDirective[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new support for Angular content in angular-leaflet-directive:

```
var html = '<br><span ng-class="thumbsUpClass(item)" ' +
    'ng-click="addChoice(item,set)"><span class="popup-container"><span ' +
    'class="icon-stack thumbs-up-stack"><i class="icon-sign-blank ' +
    'icon-stack-base"></i><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></span></span></span>';

... 

$scope.markers.push( { lat: ...,
                       lng: ...,
                       message: html,
                       getMessageScope: function() { return $scope; },          
});
```

Comment: Great catch! I wonder why there's no example on the site... However, `compileMessage` might also have to be set to `true` in the object you pass to the `push` method in the latest version of the plugin. Also, this only works for markers and not paths etc.